# miktex configuration - editor

Tags: miktex

I would like to alter the configuration on my MikTeX 2.9 system. I'm using the portable version.
A problem I have is that when I run initexmf it always uses Microsoft notepad to read configuration files.

Is it possible to change this? Notepad appears to expect only carriage return / linefeed pairs to delimited line endings.
And then things get mangled when I cut and paste to/from other text editors.

Comment: `Right click -> open with ... <YourPreferredTextEditor>`?

Comment: Thinking about it, that question is off topic here, since it it just a question of text editing/text editor in general. It has nothing to do with MikTeX or LaTeX in any way.

Comment: @Johannes_B: No it is a question about how to configure miktex. In miktex you can open local configuration files with the command `initexmf --edit-config-file` and this uses notepad.exe. I have no idea if notepad.exe is hardcoded or if there is some environment variable to change it and I never care to find out: One doesn't change the configuration files very often and I never had to copy and paste a lot to do it.

Comment: I checked in an (older) copy of the miktex sources I had still on my PC and there `notepad.exe` is hardcoded in the initexmf.cpp. So you would have to make a feature request to change this. (But I don't understand the problem with the copy&paste. Are you sure another editor would help? As soon as a config file exists you naturally can open it with every editor you want.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I wasn't aware that notepad is opened by another command. But as you also said, as soon as a text file exists, it's your choice how to open/edit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the Responses. Ulrike has the answer - since it's probably still hard-coded. (Maybe I'm lame since I guess the annoyance (once or twice a year) isn't worth a Feature request.